# ajax firing multiple times after database becomes unlocked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm having a problem with an ajax call.
I have some code set up to run a function every 2 seconds which looks to see if the content has been updated or not with WordPress ajax, does some work with php, then updates a database:

```
window.setInterval( "updateContent()", 2000 );

function updateContent(){    

    if($('#needcontent').hasClass('yes')){
       CONTENT.updateContent( 'monitor' , ids ); 
    }

}

$(function() {  

    CONTENT= {

        updateContent: function(callback, data){

            data = {            
                action: 'myplugin_do_ajax',
                callback: callback,
                data: data                              
            };

            $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){

                switch(data.callback){

                    case 'monitor' :

                        data_returned = eval("(" + response + ")");

                        if(data_returned.completed == 'true'){
                            //Adjust the DOM because there was a content update, and remove the class "yes" from #needcontent to stop the check until next time
                        }
                        else{
                            //Do nothing because no content was found, let the Interval run again
                        }

                    break;

                }


            }

    }

}
```

The problem I'm finding is that sometimes the content is quite large, and ends up locking the table while php updates the database. The ajax call runs once, runs into a database lock, and doens't return anything until the database is unlocked again. The database could be locked for a 10 second period, resulting in 1 run and 4 not-run calls.

**UPDATE:
It's not the database locking, it's the php function taking longer than 2 seconds to return, causing the Interval to loop again and again without a response.**

What's happening is those 4 not-run ajax calls then begin to fire one right after the other like they are trying to catch up or something.

I've tried increasing the Interval time to 10 seconds, but that doesn't solve the problem because if the database is locked for 11 seconds it'll still fire twice.

I've tried using global variables in Javascript (yuck) to stop the Interval from calling the function, but that doesn't seem to work either.

**UPDATE 2:
I answered my own question below to what worked for me.**

Comment: don't use `setInterval` , use `setTimeout` within ajax success instead

Comment: @charlietfl - thank you. You set my mind towards the solution that solved this for me

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
window.updateCheck= window.setInterval( "updateContent()", 2000 );

function updateContent(){    

    if($('#needcontent').hasClass('yes')){
       CONTENT.updateContent( 'monitor' , ids );
       clearInterval(window.updateCheck);
    }

}

$(function() {  

    CONTENT= {

        updateContent: function(callback, data){

            data = {            
                action: 'myplugin_do_ajax',
                callback: callback,
                data: data                              
            };
            if(window.ajaxCall) window.ajaxCall.abort();

            window.ajaxCall= $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response){
                window.updateCheck= window.setInterval( "updateContent()", 2000 );
                switch(data.callback){

                    case 'monitor' :

                        data_returned = eval("(" + response + ")");

                        if(data_returned.completed == 'true'){
                            //Adjust the DOM because there was a content update, and remove the class "yes" from #needcontent to stop the check until next time
                        }
                        else{
                            //Do nothing because no content was found, let the Interval run again
                        }

                    break;

                }


            }

    }

}
```

what we did here was to put the interval in a global variable, and also the ajax call ($.post() call actually), then when the conditions of updating is checked, we stop the interval, kill all the other active or queued request and send the ajax request to the server.

while the request is being sent to the server the update checks are stopped, then as soon as the server responds to the request we start the update check again!

Comment: `try this` is hardly an explanation of what your solution changes in OP code or approach. People shouldn't need to use a diff tool to know where the differences are

Comment: @charlietfl I was writing the explanation! sorry for the delay

Comment: While this is a great answer and would be applicable to other situations, I wanted to try and stay away from using a setInterval in a global space. Mainly because it would have involved a major code rewrite. See my answer for how I solved this.

Answer (score 0):

charlietfl's comment on my OP got me thinking about the difference between setInterval and setTimeout, and I realized that:

a) setInterval would continuously run, regardless if a result is returned or not. In my case, using ajax, the function was being call asynchronously so the setInterval wouldn't care if a result was returned.

b) If I changed the code to use setTimeout, I could control the outcome more.

This is what I did.

Firstly, remove the setInterval function completely, it's not needed.

Then I changed my switch case to this:

```
case 'monitor' :

    var monitor = false;

    data_returned = eval("(" + response + ")");

    if(data_returned.completed == 'true'){
        //Adjust the DOM because there was a content update, and remove the class "yes" from #needcontent to stop the check until next time
    }
    else{
        //Run the monitor after a 2 second timeout. 
        var ids = j('.contentDiv').attr('id');
        window.setTimeout(CONTENT.updateContent( 'monitor' , ids ) , 2000);
    }

break;
```